# Should we get rid of the [data] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

As it currently stands, the 8th most used tag on OpenData.SX is [data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data).

In my opinion, this tag is much too broad and should be replaced with narrower, more fitting tags. After all, the whole site is about data — it's even in our name ;)

What do you think? Are there any arguments for keeping the [data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) tag around?

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me. Let me know if you need [any help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/1438).

Comment: Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Get rid of it. It's already the theme of the site and has the negative effect of not using meaningful tags.